# Dropdown model is not showing in html view - Django

Tags: django, dropdown

I'm new in Django, I researched how to create drop-down. I tried everything, but still, the dropdown is not showing in HTML view.
My sample script is this.

This is the model.py

```
from django.db import models

class samplemodel(models.Model):
    list = (
            ('sample1','SAMPLE1'),
            ('sample2','SAMPLE2'),
        )

    list_choices = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=list)
```

The forms.py

```
from .models import samplemodel
from django.forms import ModelForm

class sampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = samplemodel
        fields = ['list_choices']
```

This is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import samplemodel
from .forms import sampleForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class sampleView(CreateView):
    model = samplemodel
    form_class = sampleForm
    template_name = 'home/sample.html'
```

This is the home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Home</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <form class="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I tried everything that I saw on the internet. But I can't still show the drop-down. I don't know if the `imports` are the issue or not.

Comment: Where are you accessing your `sampleModel` in home.html? I can't see anything that references it.

Comment: @Sam, Hello I just researched this, and this is the only instructions that I got.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#CharField

Comment: what is it showing in html? i can see you have same choices `list = (('sample','SAMPLE'), ('sample','SAMPLE'), )` try changing it make them like  (('sample1','SAMPLE1'), ('sample2','SAMPLE2'), )

Comment: also run `makemigrations` and then `migrate` after that

Comment: @Satendra, nothing shows in html. The choices is not the same, I just putted sample words. I also run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Answer (score 0):

you model should be like this

```html
from django.db import models
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    list = (
            ('sample1','SAMPLE1'),
            ('sample2','SAMPLE2'),
        )

    list_choices = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=list)
```

in your urlconf

```html
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from app.models import Samplemodel
from django.forms import ModelForm
url(r'^sample_form$',CreateView.as_view(model=SampleModel, template_name='home/sample.html', success_url='index', name='sample_form'))
```

thats all you don't need forms.py . django will take care of everything

Comment: Hello sir, I'm getting this kind of error `CreateView() received an invalid keyword 'name'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.`

Comment: What if I don't want to use the form to create something? I just want to select from the objects in a model class.